# Python, finding error in near symmetric matrix created by df.pivot

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, scikit-learn

I have a 16,000x 16,000 symmetric matrix which I am attempting to perform a multi dimensional scaling analysis on using sklearn. I need to use my own matrix because I have created a unique dissimilarity calculation. The calculations were performed before using df.pivot and all calculations were performed using np.float64 types.

When I run the analysis, I get a symmetric error shown below:

```
    C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_symmetric(array=memmap([[ 0.        ,  0.0364484 ,  0.02794817, ... 0.33687222,
          1.        ,  0.        ]]), tol=1e-10, raise_warning=True, raise_exception=True)
    633     else:
    634         symmetric = np.allclose(array, array.T, atol=tol)
    635 
    636     if not symmetric:
    637         if raise_exception:
--> 638             raise ValueError("Array must be symmetric")
    639         if raise_warning:
    640             warnings.warn("Array is not symmetric, and will be converted "
    641                           "to symmetric by average with its transpose.")
    642         if sp.issparse(array):

ValueError: Array must be symmetric
```

When looking through the data manually it looks perfect, but given so many columns and rows, I would not be surprised if there was an error or two created from the initial pairwise column/row groupings from the initial data I received which got included and caused confusion in the df.pivot command.

The question is thus, how do I find the one or two non-symmetric values in a dissimilarity matrix this large so that I can clear the np.allclose error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes you are probably interested in knowing if those errors are small or not. You might use the following demo, which:

- creates some erroneous sym-matrix
- checks symmetry using the same function used in your code (internally)
- prints out the max-error in absolute terms

Now: if the observed errors are small, it might be due to fp-math depending on your processings. If not, there is probably something seriously broken.

When having small errors, you might use sklearn's util-function, which actually provides a repaired matrix (by averaging; probably the best you can do without domain-specific information), as indicated in your stack-trace, although this is not used for you as this function is [called with](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/manifold/mds.py#L70):

```
dissimilarities = check_symmetric(dissimilarities, raise_exception=True)
```

Demo:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_symmetric

A_ = np.random.random(size=(1000, 1000))
A = A_.dot(A_.T)
A[2,1] += 1e-2

A_repaired = check_symmetric(A)       # default: raise_warning=True, raise_exception=False)
print('max error: ', np.amax(np.abs(A - A.T)))        
print('max error repaired: ', np.amax(A_repaired - A_repaired.T))
```

Output:

```
C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:709: 
UserWarning: Array is not symmetric, and will be converted to symmetric by 
average with its transpose.
  warnings.warn("Array is not symmetric, and will be converted "
max error:  0.00999999999999
max error repaired:  0.0
```

Comment: That worked wonders. I had tried rounding, but still only came back with tol 1e-6 compared to the needed 1e-10... The check_symmetric worked perfectly without changing almost any of the data at all. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to understand where the comparison fails:

```
np.where(~np.close(array, array.T))
```

where the tilde (~) is the logical negation.